# How to Call a function from python terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

In this example how to call "**function func_call_from_terminal**" from python terminal when the code running?

example: The name of the python script is "**TEST.py**"

```
def func_call_from_terminal():
     # in this function I need to print I_Value ... 
     # where this function must call from terminal during...
     # the running script TEST.py.

if __name__ == "__main__":
   I_Value = 1
   Flag = True
   while Flag :
       I_Value += 1
       if I_Value == 1e9
           Flag  = False
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "python terminal"? If you're running a script, you need to put the function call in the script. Do you mean you want to interrupt the script while it's running?

Comment: Take a look at the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

Comment: My bad, I mean from terminal, no I won't interrupt the script I just need to call the  function from terminal for example :  >python func_call_from_terminal.py

Comment: You could make the script check `sys.argv` and call the function depending on the arguments.

Comment: What value of `I`?

Comment: Please edit the question with all the details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: But `I` doesn't come from the command line, it's initialized as `I=1`.

Answer (score 3):

Just open terminal and use this command

```
python -c 'import TEST; TEST.func_call_from_terminal()'
```